# How to create a single depth contour line from a bathymetric raster?

Tags: raster, arcgis-9.3

I have bathymetric data (raster form) that I'm trying to tease out specific depth contours.  For example, I would like to "create" the 150-m depth contour from the bathymetric data in the Gulf of Alaska.  By using the Raster Calculator, I was able to create a raster of just the 150 m depth cells.  However, I would like these to be connected as a "smooth" contour line.  I'm having a hard time thinking of how to go about this.  I hope this makes sense!

Comment: This is a button push, as the reply indicates.  However, it's better *not* to extract the 150 m-depth cells: contouring uses information from the neighboring cells, too, and eliminating them can produce strange (and even broken) contours.  Just apply the `contour` tool to the *original* grid.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Contour tool to do it: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Using%20the%20ArcGIS%20Spatial%20Analyst%20toolbar%20to%20create%20contours

Select your raster, then choose an interval of 150m. From there, you can select and extract just the 150m contour and export that to a new shapefile or feature class.